# showing 4 video at same time in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, task, task-parallel-library

I want to show 4 videos at the same time in Windows Forms using Task. I have 4 video play clicks. When I click the first video play button, first video plays, when I click the second video play button, second video plays and first video continue to play at same time. **But**, when I click third video play button; first video stops and second video and third video plays at the same time. In the same way, when I click the fourth video play button, the second video stops, just third and fourth video plays at the same time.

My code:

```
private async void play1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inputPath = textBox1.Text;
    await Task.Run(() => {
        ReadFrames1(inputPath); }); 
}
```

and

```
public void ReadFrames1(string inputPath)
{
    using (var vFReader = new VideoFileReader())
    {
        vFReader.Open(inputPath);
        for (int i = 0; i < vFReader.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            Bitmap videoFrame = vFReader.ReadVideoFrame();
            System.Drawing.Image pic = resizeImage(new Bitmap(videoFrame), new Size(305, 267));
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pic);
        }
        vFReader.Dispose();
        vFReader.Close();
    }
}
```

`play2_Click()`, `play3_Click()`, `play4_Click()` methods are same with `play1_Click()`. (I mean for example `play2_Click()` method calls `ReadFrames2()` and shows on `PictureBox2`.) Where I am wrong?

Comment: You cannot access the GUI control (pictureBox) from another thread. You must use [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2). See [How to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For multithreading via WinForms use [BackgroundWorker](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2010/11/18/Multithreading-in-WinForms.aspx?Page=2).

here is a code example which works for me. hope it will help you:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private BackgroundWorker CreateBackgroundWorker()
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += ReadFrames;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        return worker;
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
        RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button playButton = (Button) e.Result;
        playButton.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void ReadFrames(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = (BackgroundWorker) sender;
        (string path, PictureBox pictureBox, Button playButton) arguments = ((string, PictureBox, Button)) e.Argument;
        using(var vFReader = new VideoFileReader())
        {
            vFReader.Open(arguments.path);
            for (int i = 0; i < vFReader.FrameCount; i++)
            {
                arguments.pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(vFReader.ReadVideoFrame(), arguments.pictureBox.Size);
            }
            vFReader.Dispose();
            vFReader.Close();
        }
        e.Result = arguments.playButton;
    }

    private void play1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = CreateBackgroundWorker();
        worker.RunWorkerAsync((textBox1.Text, pictureBox1, play1));
        play1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void play2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = CreateBackgroundWorker();
        worker.RunWorkerAsync((textBox2.Text, pictureBox2, play2));
        play2.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void play3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = CreateBackgroundWorker();
        worker.RunWorkerAsync((textBox3.Text, pictureBox3, play3));
        play3.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void play4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = CreateBackgroundWorker();
        worker.RunWorkerAsync((textBox4.Text, pictureBox4, play4));
        play4.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: thank you, i will try to understand Backgrounworker and then i will write here.